# How can insert formula in excel sheet using phpexcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have checked many sites for solution of my problem but not found proper solution.
I want to insert formula which will calculate the total of marks obtained by students. Marks will will be entered by teachers. I have written the php code which is downloading the excel file after inserting students names from database and maxmarks.
My excel file look like this kindly see the image as I don't have 10 reputation I am not allowed to insert image in post, please follow this link http://cbsecsnip.in/Capture.JPG 
Marks column is blank where teacher will marks other data are fetched from database and Percentage column need a formula which will calculate the marks automatically when teacher enter marks. Filled column and Percentage column is protected. I using PHPExcel.
Here is php code which is generating this excel file

```
<?php
$host='localhost'; $user='vishal'; $pass='*****'; $DataBase='school';//define the correct values
// open the connexion to the databases server
$Link=@mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$DataBase) or die('Can\'t connect !');
mysqli_set_charset($Link, 'utf8');//if not by default

//your request
$SQL="SELECT `admissionnumber`,`pre_name`,`pre_fathersoccupation`,`pre_motheroccupation` FROM `es_preadmission` WHERE `pre_class`=25 AND `pre_fromdate`>='2014-04-01' AND `pre_todate`<='2015-03-31'";
$rs=mysqli_query($Link, $SQL);//get the result (ressource)
$SQL1="SELECT a.`total_marks`,a.`pass_marks`,b.es_subjectname FROM `es_exam_details` as a JOIN `es_subject` as b ON a.`subject_id`=b.`es_subjectid` JOIN es_exam_academic as c ON c.es_exam_academicid=a.academicexam_id WHERE es_subjectshortname=25";
$rs1=mysqli_query($Link, $SQL1);//get the result (ressource)
$SQL2="SELECT distinct(b.es_subjectname) as subjects FROM `es_exam_details` as a JOIN `es_subject` as b ON a.`subject_id`=b.`es_subjectid` JOIN es_exam_academic as c ON c.es_exam_academicid=a.academicexam_id WHERE es_subjectshortname=25";

$rs2=mysqli_query($Link, $SQL2);//get the result (ressource)
while($objResult1 =mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs2)){
    $subjects[] = $objResult1["subjects"];
} 
while($objResult =mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs1)){
    $totalmarks[] = $objResult["total_marks"];
    $term[] = $objResult["aca_term_name"]; 
}

$totalStudents=array();
while($objResult =mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)){
$totalStudents[] = $objResult;
}

$Sa1Sa2marks=60;
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

// read in the existing file
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("blank.xls");

// modify/insert data in worksheet cells
$styleArray = array(
  'borders' => array(
     'outline' => array(
        'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN,
           'color' => array('argb' => '000000'),
             ),
       ),
       'fill' => array(
          'type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
          'color' => array('rgb' => '686868')
        )
);

$F=$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
$G=$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$G->getProtection()->setSheet(true);

// for 1st row heading subject heading setting 
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells("A1:B1")->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0,1, "Subject");
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:B1')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(40);

// for 2nd row heading subject heading setting 

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells("A2:B2")->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0,2, "Term");
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A2')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A2:B2')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(40);

// for 3rd row heading subject heading setting 
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells("A3:B3")->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0,3, "Exam");
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A3')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A3:B3')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(40);

// for 4th row heading subject heading setting 
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A4', "ROLL");
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A4')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A4')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B4', "NAME");
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B4')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B4')->applyFromArray($styleArray);

//subject list setting
$row=1;
$coumnStart=1;
$subjectCtr=0;
foreach($subjects as $subject)
{   
$coumnStart++;
$StartcolumnIndex=PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($coumnStart);
$EndcolumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex(($coumnStart-1) + 13);

// 1st row
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells($StartcolumnIndex.$row.':'.$EndcolumnIndex.$row)->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($coumnStart,1, $subject);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($StartcolumnIndex.$row)->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($StartcolumnIndex.$row.':'.$EndcolumnIndex.$row)->applyFromArray($styleArray);

// 2nd  row for Term1
$EndcolumnIndex2 = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex(($coumnStart-1) + 6);

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells($StartcolumnIndex.($row+1).':'.$EndcolumnIndex2.($row+1))->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($coumnStart,2, 'TERM 1');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($StartcolumnIndex.($row+1))->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($StartcolumnIndex.($row+1).':'.$EndcolumnIndex2.($row+1))->applyFromArray($styleArray);

//for FA1 Sem setting param
$semIndex=$coumnStart;
$EndcolumnIndex2 = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex(($semIndex-1) + 2);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells($StartcolumnIndex.($row+2).':'.$EndcolumnIndex2.($row+2))->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($semIndex,3, 'FA1');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($StartcolumnIndex.($row+2))->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($StartcolumnIndex.($row+2).':'.$EndcolumnIndex2.($row+2))->applyFromArray($styleArray);
$semIndex=$semIndex+2;

//for FA2
$StartcolumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($semIndex);
$EndcolumnIndex2 = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex(($semIndex-1) + 2);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells($StartcolumnIndex.($row+2).':'.$EndcolumnIndex2.($row+2))->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($semIndex,3, 'FA2');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($StartcolumnIndex.($row+2))->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($StartcolumnIndex.($row+2).':'.$EndcolumnIndex2.($row+2))->applyFromArray($styleArray);
$semIndex=$semIndex+2;

//for SA1
$StartcolumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($semIndex);
$EndcolumnIndex2 = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex(($semIndex-1) + 2);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells($StartcolumnIndex.($row+2).':'.$EndcolumnIndex2.($row+2))->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($semIndex,3, 'SA1');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($StartcolumnIndex.($row+2))->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($StartcolumnIndex.($row+2).':'.$EndcolumnIndex2.($row+2))->applyFromArray($styleArray);
$semIndex=$semIndex+2;

// for Term2
$StartcolumnIndex2=PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex(($coumnStart) + 6);
$EndcolumnIndex2 = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($coumnStart + 12);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells($StartcolumnIndex2.($row+1).':'.$EndcolumnIndex2.($row+1))->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($coumnStart+6,2, 'TERM 2');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($StartcolumnIndex2.($row+1))->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($StartcolumnIndex2.($row+1).':'.$EndcolumnIndex2.($row+1))->applyFromArray($styleArray);

//FA3
$StartcolumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($semIndex);
$EndcolumnIndex2 = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex(($semIndex-1) + 2);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells($StartcolumnIndex.($row+2).':'.$EndcolumnIndex2.($row+2))->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($semIndex,3, 'FA3');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($StartcolumnIndex.($row+2))->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($StartcolumnIndex.($row+2).':'.$EndcolumnIndex2.($row+2))->applyFromArray($styleArray);
$semIndex=$semIndex+2;

//FA4
$StartcolumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($semIndex);
$EndcolumnIndex2 = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex(($semIndex-1) + 2);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells($StartcolumnIndex.($row+2).':'.$EndcolumnIndex2.($row+2))->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($semIndex,3, 'FA4');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($StartcolumnIndex.($row+2))->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($StartcolumnIndex.($row+2).':'.$EndcolumnIndex2.($row+2))->applyFromArray($styleArray);
$semIndex=$semIndex+2;

//SA2
$StartcolumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($semIndex);
$EndcolumnIndex2 = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex(($semIndex-1) + 2);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells($StartcolumnIndex.($row+2).':'.$EndcolumnIndex2.($row+2))->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($semIndex,3, 'SA2');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($StartcolumnIndex.($row+2))->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($StartcolumnIndex.($row+2).':'.$EndcolumnIndex2.($row+2))->applyFromArray($styleArray);
$semIndex=$semIndex+2;

// every 13th column total marks & precentage
$totalMarksColumIndex=PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($coumnStart + 12);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($coumnStart+12,3, 'TOTAL MARKS');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($totalMarksColumIndex.($row+2))->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($totalMarksColumIndex.($row+2))->applyFromArray($styleArray);

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($coumnStart+12,4, 'PERCENTAGE');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($totalMarksColumIndex.($row+3))->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($totalMarksColumIndex.($row+3))->applyFromArray($styleArray);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($totalMarksColumIndex)->setWidth(20);

// putting marks column heading
$flag=1;
for($i=$coumnStart;$i<$coumnStart+12;$i=$i+1)
{
$MarksheadingIndex=PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($i);    
 if($flag%2==1) 
  {
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($i,4, 'MARKS');
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($MarksheadingIndex)->getProtection()->setLocked(PHPExcel_Style_Protection::PROTECTION_UNPROTECTED);
  }
 else 
  {
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($i,4, 'MAXMARKS');
    // setting the max marks
      for($j=5;$j<count($totalStudents)+5;$j++){
        if($flag%6==0)
        {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($i,$j, $Sa1Sa2marks);    
        }
        else if($flag==2 || $flag==8)
        {
         $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($i,$j, 40);  
        }
        else
        {
         $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($i,$j, 20);     
        }
      }
  }

 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($MarksheadingIndex.($row+3))->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($MarksheadingIndex.($row+3))->applyFromArray($styleArray); 
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($MarksheadingIndex)->setWidth(15);
$flag++;    
}

$coumnStart=($coumnStart-1)+13; $subjectCtr++;
}

// putting students name with rollno

$Line=5;
 foreach($totalStudents as $student){//extract each record
        $studentName= $student['pre_name'];
        if($student['pre_fathersoccupation']!=''){$studentName.=' '.$student['pre_fathersoccupation'];}
        if($student['pre_motheroccupation']!=''){$studentName.=' '.$student['pre_motheroccupation'];}
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$Line,  $student['admissionnumber']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$Line,  $studentName);
    ++$Line;
       }

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="newFile.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output'); 

?>
```

If any Expert guide me how can I do this I will be thankful to all of them

Comment: If those passwords are in any case close to real values, I suggest editing them to some fake data (foo, bar, etc).

Comment: still localhost, nobody cares

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Mark Baker Thank you for show the way I tried and done like this -

```
$calculatRow='';
    for($ctr=0;$ctr < count($marksColumnArr);$ctr++)
    {
    $calculatRow.='(($'.$marksColumnArr[$ctr].'##/$'.$maXmarksColumnArr[$ctr].'$##)*'.$divisionVal[$ctr].')+';      
}
$calculateArrbyRow=substr($calculatRow,0,-1);    
// Replicate formula by row

 for($j=5;$j<count($totalStudents)+5;$j++){
   $formula=str_replace('##',$j,$calculateArrbyRow);
   $cell=PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($coumnStart+12);
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($cell.$j, '='.$formula);
 }    
$coumnStart=($coumnStart-1)+13; $subjectCtr++;
}
```

Answer (score 64):

Read section 4.6.4 of the developer documentation, and examples like `03formulas.php`.

You can write a formula as you'd write it in Excel itself, simply store the formula prefixed with `=` in the cell

e.g.

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValue(
        'E10',
        '=SUM(A10:E9)'
    );
```

Will write the formula `=SUM(A10:E9)` in cell `E10`

When writing a formula to a cell, remember that:

- Decimal separator is `.` (period)
- Function argument separator is `,` (comma)
- Matrix row separator is `;` (semicolon)
- English function names must be used

**EDIT**

```
for ($row = 1; $row <= 10; $row++) {
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
        ->setCellValue(
            'J' . $row,
            '=SUM(A'.$row.':C'.$row.')/10 + SUM(D'.$row.':F'.$row.')/20 + SUM(G'.$row.':I'.$row.')/60'
        );
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mark for your kind consideration but how can change the row number. like if cell J1 contain formula `=SUM(A1:C1)/10 + SUM(D1:F1)/20 + SUM (G1:I1)/60 for cell J1` now for 2nd row I need formula `=SUM(A2:C2)/10 + SUM(D2:F2)/20 + SUM (G2:I2)/60 for J2` and repeat for all students here I am stuck how i will **change the Row Number

Comment: You build the formula dynamically.... the formula string is only a PHP string, so you can concatenate it, and anything else that you can do to build PHP strings;

Comment: I will be sincerely grateful if you can help me with a sample code snippet.

Comment: No, you asked a question that's so easy, but I don't know how I can simplify my answer any further

Comment: just a note for non-english users: you must enter formula in english, becase is you Excel that do real-time localization of the formula from/to the english. Into the file you must use only english formulas.

Comment: @realtebo - There is an option to set a locale/language that provides a translator to/from that locale/language and English, it's described in the PHPExcel docs

Comment: @MarkBaker: really? I didn't know. Thanks. An hint about where to find this info?

Comment: @realtebo - section of the docs entitled [Locale Settings for Formulae](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/08-Recipes.md#locale-settings-for-formulae).... best viewed in the Word/PDF versions of the docs until I fix the UTF-8 encoding in the markdown version