# Embed a hyperlink in Excel after it is generated

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter

I have created my Excel file. It sets data from database and it works fine. Now I want to have one column (`Image`) to be an URL and when clicked, the download starts. In the `Image` column, the name of the image is set just like other values from database. My code sample for the columns:

```
              $this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('C'.$j, $Cooperation->getPhone());
              $this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('C'.$j, $Cooperation->getImage());
              $this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('D'.$j, $Cooperation->getEmail());
              $this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('E'.$j, $Cooperation->getMajor());
              $this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('F'.$j, $Cooperation->getLastDegree());
              $this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('G'.$j, $Cooperation->getJobCategory());
              $this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('H'.$j, $Cooperation->getName() ." ". $Cooperation->getLastName());
```

This is what I tried for the image column:

```
 $this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('H'.$j, echo '<a href="/media/images/footer/'.$Cooperation['Image'].'">'.$Cooperation['Image'].'</a>'
```

Comment: You could maybe use a `=HYPERLINK()` formula for this.

Comment: You mean the Excel formula? in PHP? is that even possible?!

Comment: I don't know - I'm not familiar with the particular library you're using to create the Excel file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21302389/how-can-insert-formula-in-excel-sheet-using-phpexcel

Answer (score 2):

PHP isn't my strong suit but something like this:

```
$this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('J'.$row,
 '=HYPERLINK("/media/images/footer/'.$Cooperation['Image'].
 '",'.$Cooperation['Image'].')');
```

You might also need to use a full path unless the files will be located in some fixed location relative to the Excel file.

You'll likely have to tidy up those quotes.

Comment: Your way of doing was alright that why +1 is given but for your information, I created it in this way.
$this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('B'.$j,'=HYPERLINK("http://website-url.com/media/images/footer/'.$Cooperation->getImage().'")');
Same way as yours with a mild modification.
Thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getCell("H1")->setValue('=Hyperlink("https://www.Example.com/","Sample")');
```